# Blazor FluentValidation Dynamic Rule Generation C#

Tags: c#, blazor, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to create validation rules for Pocos in a generic fashion. I'm fairly confident with Reflection, but I don't really want to pick apart the entire call chain to be able to do what I want.

I came up with the idea of detecting all of the types in use and calling a generic function that could setup the rest of the rule, but I can't find anywhere in the chain that exposes the actual object.

This is a nested structure where panels in my form are based on a property whose type is 'object', I want to know at which point I can get the actual value of the instance. A rule chain for me looks like follows:

```
   RuleForEach(p => p.level1s)
       .ChildRules(l1 => {
            x.RuleForEach(p => p.level2s)
            .ChildRules(l2 => {

                 //ToDo: Iterate Properties on Type @ level1s[].level2s[].poco
                 //How can I find type of poco for this specific executing of this lambda?

                 //For each property, I'd have to do reflective code for this kind of thing
                 //ToDo: l2.RuleFor<~~TProperty~~>(x => x.poco~~property~~).NotEmpty()
                 //        .When(x => x.poco~~property~~ has the RequiredAttribute)
                 //        .WithMessage("{PropertyName} is required");
            });
       });
```

So, if you can tell from my pseudo code above, I would need to be able to extract the type of the Poco, and the type of the properties within the last ChildRules expression, but all that I have to hand is an InlineValidator<~~l2type~~, object> - so how/where can the current instance type of that 'object' be determined?

Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a while and thinking about it from several angles it occurred to me that I should be able to just pass through a validator for my Poco, but a problem occurred when trying to pick up the validator from my variable.

In my first/outer validator, I ended up with the following code:

```
                        //ddeach is just the output of a RuleForEach
                        ddeach.ChildRules(kvconfig =>
                        {
                            //Note - Fluent Validation requires that each rule is stated in full at this point starting with a RuleFor, so it's not
                            //possible to merge all of these following code blocks

                            //Chain Child Validator
                            kvconfig.RuleFor(kv => kv.Value.RefPoco)
                            .SetValidator(dict => (IValidator<object>)dict.Value.PocoValidator);
                        });
```

My property at dict.Value.PocoValidator is just an 'IValidator' but FluentValidation doesn't supply an easy way to use one of those, it has to be a strong type to support the fluent API. You can't give it a IValidator, because you don't know the type and LINQ can't infer it, also it won't automatically cast to IValidator.

Eventually, I found that I could allow my validator class to be used by implementing IValidator. My validator code then looks like:

```
    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<MyPocoType>, IValidator<object>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        }

        FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult IValidator<object>.Validate(object instance)
        {
            return this.Validate(instance as MyPocoType);
        }

        async Task<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult> IValidator<object>.ValidateAsync(object instance, CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            return await this.ValidateAsync(instance as MyPocoType, cancellation);
        }
    }
```

```
Mark
```